# Argo accessing created files

Tags: file, local, argo-workflows

I am using Argo to implement my workflow which contains several bash commands and creates files and folders on Argo. The issue is tat I couldn't find a clear way to access the created files locally. Is there a way to link a folder locally to the folder that get created by Argo in order to access the created files?

Answer (score 1):

Argo Workflows steps run as containers. Those containers run on a Kubernetes cluster (either on your computer or on someone else's computer(s)). The files created within those containers exist on some filesystem. That filesystem may or may not be persistent and easily accessible on your computer or on the remote cluster. So it's not easy to prescribe some one-size-fits-all way to directly access the files.

The standard way to access files created in Argo Workflows is to define them as [output artifacts](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/output-artifact-s3.yaml). Those output artifacts are lifted from the container's filesystem and sent to your configured [artifact repository](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/configure-artifact-repository/) after the Workflow step is finished.

The easiest way to set up an artifact repository is to install Argo Workflow manifests which already include the manifests/configuration for an artifact repository (Minio, which is an S3 implementation). The [quick start guide](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/quick-start/) comes with a Minio artifact repository pre-configured.

After running your Argo Workflow, with your target file defined as an output artifact, port-forward Minio so that you can load its interface.

```sh
kubectl port-forward -n argo svc/minio 9000:9000
```

Load http://localhost:9000 and navigate through the Minio interface to locate and download your artifact.